# Keyboard shortcuts for keyboard keys that don't Work

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, acer-aspire

Is there any program that can help me create keyboard shortcuts to emulate the keyboard keys that are not functioning. For. eg. Can I press `Fn + 1` to emulate `W` and `Fn + 2` for `Tab`. Anything comes to mind?

2 keys on my laptop keyboard are not functioning since a couple of days. They are `W` and `Tab`. i sent it to a repair man, he says, something is not right, and he is not able to fix it.

At this moment, I am trying to scram through my vocabulary to find Words that don't include the letter `W` and avoiding shortcuts, as `Tab` key is not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Windows...

The program [SharpKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/) can be used to remap keyboard keys. This program writes directly to the registry and therefore is probably the best way to achieve a key remap.

This program recently was recommended by [PC Magazine](https://www.pcmag.com/feature/362116/how-to-remap-your-keyboard). The PC Magazine link provides a good tutorial on how to remap the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Works like a charm. I can now use words that contain the letter `W`. and also `Tab`